# SQL Server Merge with case?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, merge, case

Hello guys here with another question, regarding sql server 2008 r2 this time about the merge, is it possible to have a case inside the update portion of the merge?

Because its telling me

Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 9
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CASE'.

```
MERGE INTO PERSONAFISICA AS TARGET
USING dbo.#temp1 AS SOURCE
ON TARGET.RFC = SOURCE.RFC AND TARGET.APATERNO = SOURCE.APELLIDO_PATERNO AND
TARGET.AMATERNO = SOURCE.Apellido_Materno
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET
TARGET.NUM_CLIENTE = 0,
TARGET.NOMBRE1 = LEFT(SOURCE.Nombre,CHARINDEX(' ', SOURCE.NOMBRE + ' ') -1),
CASE 
WHEN LEN(SOURCE.NOMBRE) - LEN(REPLACE(SOURCE.NOMBRE,' ','')) >= 1
THEN 
TARGET.NOMBRE2 = SUBSTRING(SOURCE.NOMBRE, CHARINDEX(' ', SOURCE.NOMBRE)+1, LEN(SOURCE.NOMBRE))
ELSE '' END,
TARGET.APATERNO = SOURCE.Apellido_Paterno,
TARGET.AMTERNO = SOURCE.Apellido_Materno,
CASE 
WHEN SOURCE.SEXO = 'F' 
THEN TARGET.IDGENERO = 2
WHEN SOURCE.SEXO = 'M'
THEN TARGET.IDGENERO = 1
ELSE TARGET.IDGENERO = 0
END,
CASE
WHEN SOURCE.ESTADO_CIVIL = '0' 
THEN TARGET.idestado_civil = 0
WHEN SOURCE.ESTADO_CIVIL = 'C'
THEN TARGET.idestado_civil = 1
WHEN SOURCE.ESTADO_CIVIL = 'D' 
THEN TARGET.idestado_civil = 2
WHEN SOURCE.ESTADO_CIVIL = 'S'
THEN TARGET.idestado_civil = 3
WHEN SOURCE.ESTADO_CIVIL = 'V' 
THEN TARGET.idestado_civil = 5
WHEN SOURCE.ESTADO_CIVIL = 'U'
THEN TARGET.idestado_civil = 6
ELSE TARGET.idestado_civil = 0
END,
TARGET.idregimen = 0,
TARGET.saludo = SOURCE.SALUDO,
TARGET.conyuge_nombre1 = '',
TARGET.conyuge_nombre2 = '',
TARGET.conyuge_apaterno = '',
TARGET.conyuge_nombre2 = '',
TARGET.dependiente = 0,
TARGET.edad_dependiente = '',
TARGET.ididentificacion = 0,
TARGET.fecha_nacimiento = '1800-01-01',
TARGET.rfc = SOURCE.RFC,
TARGET.CURP = '',
TARGET.idnacionalidad = 0,
TARGET.email = SOURCE.Email_Personal,
TARGET.idescolaridad = SOURCE.Escolaridad
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT (num_cliente, nombre1, nombre2, apaterno, amaterno, idgenero, idestado_civil,
idregimen, saludo, conyuge_nombre1, conyuge_nombre2, conyuge_apaterno, conyuge_amaterno, dependiente,
edad_dependiente, ididentificacion, fecha_nacimiento, rfc, curp, idnacionalidad, email, idescolaridad)
VALUES (0, LEFT(nombre,CHARINDEX(' ',nombre + ' ')-1) AS [Primer Nombre],
CASE WHEN LEN(nombre) - LEN(REPLACE(nombre,' ','')) >= 1  THEN SUBSTRING(nombre, CHARINDEX(' ', nombre)+1, LEN(nombre)) ELSE '' END AS [Segundo Nombre],
Apellido_Paterno,Apellido_Materno)
CASE 
WHEN SEXO = 'F' THEN 2
WHEN SEXO = 'M' THEN 1
ELSE 0
END,
CASE 
WHEN Estado_Civil = '0' THEN 0
WHEN Estado_Civil = 'C' THEN 1
WHEN Estado_Civil = 'D' THEN 2
WHEN Estado_Civil = 'S' THEN 3
WHEN Estado_Civil = 'V' THEN 5
WHEN Estado_Civil = 'U' THEN 6
ELSE 0
END, 0, Saludo,'','','','',0,'',0,'1800-01-01',RFC,'',0,Email_Personal,Escolaridad
```

Comment: You might want to format this code by indenting it...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't use a case in that way in an update.  It needs to be like ...

```
UPDATE table
SET value1 = CASE 
    WHEN a.blah = b.blah THEN foo
    WHEN a.blah > b.blah THEN bar
    ELSE NULL
  END,
value2 = 5,
......
```

Comment: NP... sometimes it just takes a second set of eyes.